# Прошу помочь найти ошибку в слайдере

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.next').click(function() {
    var currentImage = $('.image.first');
    var currentImageIndex = $('.image.first').index();
    var nextImageIndex = currentImageIndex + 1;
    var nextImage = $('.image').eq(nextImageIndex);
    currentImage.fadeOut(1300);
    currentImage.removeClass('first');


    if (nextImageIndex == ($('.image:last').index() + 1)) {
      $('.image').eq(0).fadeIn(1300);
      $('.image').eq(0).addClass('first');
    } else {
      nextImage.fadeIn(1300);
      nextImage.addClass('first')
    }
    /*...prev...*/
  });

});
```

```css
.next {
display: block;
position: absolute;
left:1240px; 
top:390px;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: arial;
}
.prev {
display: block;
position: absolute;
left:610px;
top:390px;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: arial;
}
.slider {
position: relative;
width:500px;
height:300px;
left:0px;
top:0px;
right:0px;
margin:300px auto;
}
.image {
text-align: center;
line-height: 200px;
position:absolute;
font-size:40px;
}
.image:first-child {
background-color: #661D21;
width:500px;
}
.image:nth-child(2) {
background-color:#83A15D;
width:500px;
}
.image:nth-child(3) {
background-color:#C13DA1;
width:500px;
}
.image:nth-child(4) {
background-color:#5344BA;
width:500px;
}
.image:nth-child(5) {
background-color:#40BEA3;
width:500px;
}
a{
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="next"><a href="#">next</a></div>
<div class="prev"><a href="#">previous</a></div>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="image first">FIRST</div>
  <div class="image">SECOND</div>
  <div class="image">THIRD</div>
  <div class="image">FOURTH</div>
  <div class="image last">FIFTH</div>
</div>
```

1. Не могу найти ошибку в слайдере (написал только `next`, а уже не работает), прошу помочь. Ошибок в консоли разработчика не выдает.
2. Правилен ли здесь принцип написания простого слайдера? Может будут какие-либо советы новичку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // !!!
    
    var currentImage = $('.image.first');
    var currentImageIndex = $('.image').index(currentImage);
    var nextImageIndex = (currentImageIndex + 1) % $('.image').length;
    var nextImage = $('.image').eq(nextImageIndex);
    
    currentImage.fadeOut(1300);
    currentImage.removeClass('first');

    nextImage.fadeIn(1300);
    nextImage.addClass('first')
  });
  
  $('.image').hide();       // !!!
  $('.image.first').show(); // !!!
});
```

```css
.next {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 390px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.prev {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 390px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 300px auto;
}

.image {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 500px;
}

.image:first-child {
  background-color: #661D21;
}

.image:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #83A15D;
}

.image:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #C13DA1;
}

.image:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #5344BA;
}

.image:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #40BEA3;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="next"><a href="#">next</a></div>
<div class="prev"><a href="#">previous</a></div>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="image first">FIRST</div>
  <div class="image">SECOND</div>
  <div class="image">THIRD</div>
  <div class="image">FOURTH</div>
  <div class="image last">FIFTH</div>
</div>
```